# Save 2D array as a txt file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, file-io, numpy-ndarray

In my simulation i compute an array x with "dimensions"

```
np.shape(x)

---> (50,80)
```

To my understanding this is a two dimensional array  with 50 rows and 80 columns. When i try save x as a csv file i get an error:

```
np.savetxt('values.csv',[x])

--> ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 3D array instead
```

How can x be a 3D array? Its described by two indices (row,column) and therefore is two dimensional or not?

Comment: Why have you put x in brackets? How about removing them?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the square brackets from `x`. This is converting it to a list of one item - the array.

```
np.savetxt('values.csv',x)
```